# Group items from one list and create a new list with grouped items using Dart

Tags: flutter, list, dart

It is necessary to group items from List A if they have the same "timestamp" and then add the grouped items, and all the rest to a new List B.

Keep in mind that the "value" from List A needs to be mapped to a new corresponding field depending on the item "type". Also, "type" needs to be set in List B to "blood_pressure_measurement", in case of a successful grouping for the same "timestamp".

Also, for the items that were not grouped, the "value" also needs to be mapped to a new corresponding field depending on the item "type".

I would higly appreciate if someone would share a working Dart code with me that I can use in my Flutter app. Thank you very much!

EXAMPLE BELOW:

This is the List A, that I am starting with:

```
List A = [
    {
      "type": "systolic_blood_pressure",
      "value": 120,
      "timestamp": "2022-10-31 18:40:59.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "diastolic_blood_pressure",
      "value": 80,
      "timestamp": "2022-10-31 18:40:59.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "heart_rate",
      "value": 60,
      "timestamp": "2022-10-31 18:40:59.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "systolic_blood_pressure",
      "value": 130,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-07 12:20:40.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "diastolic_blood_pressure",
      "value": 90,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-07 12:20:40.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "heart_rate",
      "value": 80,
      "timestamp": "2021-11-07 12:20:40.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {"type": "weight",
     "value": 100,
     "timestamp": "2022-02-02 13:10:20.000",
     "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
     },
    {"type": "weight",
     "value": 98,
     "timestamp": "2022-03-01 09:11:10.000",
     "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
     },
  ];
```

And this is list B I need as a result.

```
List B = [
    {
      "type": "blood_pressure_measurement",
      "systolic_blood_pressure": "120",
      "diastolic_blood_pressure": "80",
      "heart_rate": "60",
      "timestamp": "2022-10-31 18:40:59.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "blood_pressure_measurement",
      "systolic_blood_pressure": "130",
      "diastolic_blood_pressure": "90",
      "heart_rate": "80",
      "timestamp": "2021-11-07 12:20:40.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {
      "type": "weight",
      "weight": "98",
      "timestamp": "2022-02-02 13:10:20.000",
      "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
    },
    {"type": "weight",
     "weight": "98",
     "timestamp": "2022-03-01 09:11:10.000",
     "sourceName": "com.omronhealthcare.omronconnect",
     },
  ];
```

I searched for different options and packages to manipulate the list, but I do not want to group the items only for the ListView widget, I need to change the real data itself in the list variable.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Add the codes that you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.